# TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: typescript

My project uses typescript version 3.9.7. I have to use the below code. The code is fine in TypeScript version 4.2.3.

```js
export namespace Abcd {
    export type AbcdOneParams = [xAxis: number, yAxis: number];
}
```

But in version 3.9.7, it throws error `',' expected`. Intellij shows `TS1005: ',' expected`.
[code@TS Playground 4.2.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ts=4.2.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgQQCNsATOAbwCg4a5RJY4YBPMPI0geQWAAUkoqdHAC8cANoh8IAJboAXIgCuKQsCgAaOM2lzFCFWqgBdANyUAvkA)
[code@TS Playground 3.9.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ts=3.9.7&ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgQQCNsATOAbwCg4a5RJY4YBPMPI0geQWAAUkoqdHAC8cANoh8IAJboAXIgCuKQsCgAaOM2lzFCFWqgBdANyUAvkA)
How can I update the code to use it with 3.9.7.

Comment: Typescript 4 supports [labelled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) which are not supported in 3.9 so what you need there is not possible in 3.9 , you need to remove the names `xAxis` and `yAxis`

Comment: @apokryfos you should consiider converting this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`type AbcdOneParams = [xAxis: number, yAxis: number];` is a labelled tuple type. These are only supported in TypeScript 4. For the code to work in 3.9 it needs to change to:

```
export type AbcdOneParams = [number, number];
```

For more information on this feature you can refer to the [4.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
export namespace Abcd {
    export type AbcdOneParams = [ number,  number];
}
```

You don't need to set keys in tuple type.